# How to set package latest version in Bower?

Tags: javascript, bower

I was watching this [nice video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USk1ie30z5k) about requirejs, backbone and bower and something does not work for me. How can I set latest version of package in *bower.json* file? In video Jeff says that *null* should be used to define latest version like this

```
{
    "name": "project name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "backbone-amd": null,
        "underscore-amd": null,
        "requirejs": null
    }
}
```

But I have an exception in console that I can't use *null* value as version number. I couldn't find any info at bower wiki. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What's your bower version? It works or me with 1.1.2

Comment: I've got it. I have 0.10.0 version

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That should work.

Make sure you are running the latest version of Bower.  I am currently running v1.2.6 and null works to fetch the latest dependency.

```
$ bower -v
```

If you have installed bower globally via npm, then you can update it this way:

```
$ npm update bower -g
```

Note: you may need to run that as sudo depending on your file permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, I've installed bower few months ago

Answer (score 80):

If you are using bower version `1.2.x`, this should work:

```
{
    "name": "project name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "backbone-amd": "latest",
        "underscore-amd": "latest",
        "requirejs": "latest"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `latest` keyword when installing a package. Be aware that you can get some dependencies issues :

```
bower install --save font-awesome#latest
```

> ```
> bower font-awesome#4.1.0    not-cached git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.1.0
> bower font-awesome#4.1.0       resolve git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.1.0
> bower font-awesome#4.1.0      download https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v4.1.0.tar.gz
> bower font-awesome#4.1.0       extract archive.tar.gz
> bower font-awesome#4.1.0      resolved git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.1.0
> ```

There is a [`-F` flag](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install-options) that can go even further:

> ```
> -F, --force-latest      Force latest version on conflict
> ```

Comment: just to clear it up, doing `bower install --save font-awesome#latest` even though you already have font-awesome saved in your bower.json as an older version, will prompt you to select the newer version and overwrite it.

Answer (score 16):

I have found an easy alternative, instead of updating manually, you could use one command:

First install this:

```
npm install -g bower-check-updates
```

Then run the `bcu` to check for the updates

[image: bcu]

After check, `bcu -u` to upgrade your bower.json and its done!

More details and source:

> bower-check-updates - is totally clone of npm-check-updates, but it
>   updates bower.json dependencies (bower-check-updates updates
>   bower.json).

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-check-updates

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates --packageManager bower
```

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-check-updates